# What does it mean when the webpack entry property is given an object with arrays of strings as values?

Tags: webpack

[The Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#object-syntax) allows for the possibility of an object with arrays of strings for values being passed to the `entry` property of Webpack config.

e.g.

```
Usage: entry: {[entryChunkName: string]: string|Array<string>}
```

However the documentation does not discuss what this actually means. Is this the equivalent of multiple entry points? Does this cause any different behaviour?

Here is an example of it being used in a project [serverless/aws-nodejs-typescript](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-nodejs-typescript/webpack.config.js).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An entry point can be defined in 3 ways:

**1)**

```
entry: {
 main: './src/index.js',
 dashboard: './dashboard/dashboard.js'
}
```

This creates a file for every single property in the object.

**2)**

```
entry: './src/index.js'
```

The usual configuration, not much different.

**3)**

```
entry: ['@babel/polyfill', 'src/index.js', 'otherfile', 'other something']
```

The only difference between defining as an object and defining as an array is that as an object webpack creates more than one "main" bundle file, it is also a code splitting strategy.

When defining as an array, webpack will look for dependencies in all these files and put them into the same "entry" file, basically it is categorized as 1 single file.

What is happening with that project you linked is a combination of 1 + 3, which we could say it is a "4". That creates an object for each entry and each entry on that object is composed by an array of different other libraries.

Comment: "_An entry point can be defined in 3 ways:_" . As I point out in my question though, there seems to be a 4th way. That is you can pass `entry` an object consisting of arrays of strings. You don't mention that option in your answer

Comment: oh, there is not a "4th" way so to say, it is just the combination of 1st and 3rd. You just combine those 2 concepts and that is what you get.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Would you mind adding a note about how this is being used in the example project I provided? https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-nodejs-typescript/webpack.config.js

Comment: No! i'll add that as input

Answer (score 0):

Passing an object to the `entry` means that you want to provide more details to that entrypoint. So the question becomes: what's the different between providing single and multiple file(-path) to each entry?

And you also copy-paste the key info. to understand this topic:

```js
Usage: entry: { <entryChunkName> string | [string] } | {}
```

Each entry will create a **chunk**, which can be thought of as just a *file*. When you provide an array of paths to a single entry, you're providing many modules that will be loaded into that chunk.